# An active access token must be used to query information about the current user. Facebook PHP SDK v4

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm passing the facebook login token from ember-cli to my laravel server to register/login my user but I'm stuck with this error.

{"error":{"type":"Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException","message":"An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.","file":"C:\xampp\htdocs\LoginApp\vendor\facebook\php-sdk-v4\src\Facebook\FacebookRequestException.php","line":134}}

Here is my function

```
public function authorizeFacebookUser() {
        $facebook_token = Input::get('facebook_access_token');

        FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('xxxxxxxx', 'xxxxx');

        $session = new FacebookSession((string) $facebook_token);

        if ($session) {
            // have session
            try {
                $user_profile = (new FacebookRequest(
                    $session, 'GET', '/me'
                ))->execute()->getGraphObject(GraphUser::className());

                echo "Name: " . $user_profile->getName();

            } catch(FacebookRequestException $e) {

                echo "Exception occured, code: " . $e->getCode();
                echo " with message: " . $e->getMessage();

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

After creating a session with the access_token, you should validate it to make sure it's correct and working:

```
  try {
    if ( !$session->validate() ) {
      $session = null;
    }
  } catch ( Exception $e ) {
    // catch any exceptions
    $session = null;
  }
```

Then you can make the API call to get the user's profile information. Hopefully, the above code will display any errors related to the access_token.